# Reading a stacked heading excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet where the headings (TradeDate, Value) are stacked on top of each other separated by a type(ABS, MBS), an example of the format:

```
ABS,
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,21
2019-01-22,22
MBS,
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,11
2019-01-22,12
2019-01-23,13
```

How can I load this into python, preferably pandas or another package, where I load each heading separately? The headings are unique/the same for each type and the heading index can change. Using the example above I'd want to return two separate data frames or objects.

`df_abs`

```
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,21
2019-01-22,22
```

and `df_mbs`

```
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,11
2019-01-22,12
2019-01-23,13
```

Comment: [Don't add data/code as a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). We cannot copy that to reproduce a good answer.

Comment: @Erfan Sorry I'll add a table/something copy paste able, stackoverflow did that for me when I copy pasted from excel.

Comment: @Erfan updated with copy paste able examples, imgur should not be a feature when you copy paste from excel on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit overengeneering, but couldn't find a more easy solution:

```
# Mask all the rows which have a date
m = df[0].str.match('([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))')

# Create an equal indicator on each row which has a date, but stops when value changes so we can groupby
df['ind'] = np.where(~m, 0, (m != m.shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum())

# Extract seperate dataframe into a list
dfs = [d for _, d in df[df.ind.ne(0)].groupby('ind')]

# Rename columns to expected output
dfs = [df.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:'TradeDate', 1:'Value'}) for df in dfs]
```

---

**Output**

```
for d in dfs:
    print(d,'\n')

    TradeDate Value  ind
0  2019-01-21    21    2
1  2019-01-22    22    2 

    TradeDate Value  ind
0  2019-01-21    11    4
1  2019-01-22    12    4
2  2019-01-23    13    4
```

---

**Reproducable example**

```
from io import StringIO

a = StringIO('''
ABS,
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,21
2019-01-22,22
MBS,
TradeDate,Value
2019-01-21,11
2019-01-22,12
2019-01-23,13
''')

df = pd.read_csv(a, header=None)

# Out
            0      1
0         ABS    NaN
1   TradeDate  Value
2  2019-01-21     21
3  2019-01-22     22
4         MBS    NaN
5   TradeDate  Value
6  2019-01-21     11
7  2019-01-22     12
8  2019-01-23     13
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, if the header is more complicated it could be a bit tricky with the regex but should still work.

Comment: I get what your're saying, it is hard to generalize this for _any_ scenario. @pyCthon but this suffices for your question stated as is.